# Text at Left side and Right Side in HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the HTML output similar like this -

```js
My First Sentence                       My Second Sentence
```

So, my code is -

```html
<h3>
   <span style="float:left;">My first sentence</span>
   <a href="#" style="float:right;text-align:right;">My second sentence </a>
</h3>
```

and the output was -

```js
My First SentenceMy Second Sentence
```

So I added "margin-left: 100px" to the element  and then the output was in next line-

```js
My First Sentence                       
                                 My Second Sentence
```

Please guide me through this.Most probably some other css is overwriting it and I need to know how can I get the view what I want. My current code looks like -

```html
<h3>
   <span style="float:left;">My first sentence</span>
   <a href="#" style="float:right;text-align:right;margin-left: 100px;">My second sentence </a>
</h3>
```

Comment: Your example works fine here and at https://jsfiddle.net/dsxsubqp/, are you sure some css styling you have elsewhere isn't messing it up. _"Most probably some other css is overwriting it"_ well we can't help you if we don't know what other css you have.

Comment: @PatrickEvans I am sure it is some other css which is messing but in my project there are whole lot of css file and I am not able to find out which one is actually affecting them. So I wanted to know if somehow I can make it work.

Comment: Well browsers have element / style inspectors in the developer tools, that would be a good place to start

Comment: It just need to be wrapped in a div

Comment: It keeps the elements from shifting out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked by adding margin-left:80px;. So the final code is -

```html
<h3>
   <span style="float:left;">My first sentence</span>
   <a href="#" style="float:right;text-align:right;margin-left: 80px;">My second sentence </a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 3):

i see 3 options(you used float already) with `display` and `text-align`/`text-align-last`. The choice is about *how much old the browser is* that you intend to support

```css
span,
a {
  display: inline-block;
  /* optionnal*/
}


/* newest browser */

h3.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* check it on canisue.com */

h3.tAl {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
}


/* oldest browsers such as IE8 */

h3.tA {
  text-align: justify;
}

h3.tA:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}


/* optionnal to not allow wrapping 
h3[class=^ta] {
white-space:nowrap;
}
*/
```

```html
<h3 class="flex">
  <span>My first sentence</span>
  <a href="#">My second sentence </a>
</h3>
<h3 class="tAl">
  <span>My first sentence</span>
  <a href="#">My second sentence </a>
</h3>
<h3 class="tA">
  <span>My first sentence</span>
  <a href="#">My second sentence </a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create different columns and then left align the text inside them.

```css
.row{
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.half-row{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;
  padding: 1%;
  float: left;
}

.clear{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="half-row">
    My First Sentence
  </div>
  <div class="half-row">
    My Second Sentence
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div> <!-- Needed for float handling -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just wrap it in a div to keep it in line like this.

```
 <div style="width:100%; height:2em; float:left;">
 <h3>
 <span style="float:left;">My first sentence</span>
 <a href="#" style="float:left;text-align:left;margin-left: 100px;">My second sentence </a>
 </h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: And how would wrapping it in a div help?

Comment: It contains them from shifting. you cant see that the code works.

Comment: Afraid not, if the containing element is small it isn't going to prevent shifting. And they act the same with or without the div, https://jsfiddle.net/04haadau/

Comment: Afraid you are wrong.. Run this code and see for yourself lol.

Comment: I did run it i even linked the jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes it is, look at the second group it is what you have.